# How can I view the current blockchain size?

Tags: blockchain

How can I view the current size, preferably in bytes, of the blockchain? Is there a CLI command for bitcoind? Or a website that displays the size?

Answer (score 6):

If you have the bitcoin client running in server mode, you can pass it the `getblockchaininfo` command. This is the current output:

```json
{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 525329,
  "headers": 525329,
  "bestblockhash": "000000000000000000192cf4d557fb2265855713b0fd208a6490bca81137bce4",
  "difficulty": 4306949573981.513,
  "mediantime": 1527792344,
  "verificationprogress": 0.9999976722383654,
  "chainwork": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e6cf0d64537cc800fc54f8",
  "pruned": false,
  "softforks": [
    {
      "id": "bip34",
      "version": 2,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip66",
      "version": 3,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip65",
      "version": 4,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "csv": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": 1462060800,
      "timeout": 1493596800,
      "since": 419328
    },
    "segwit": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": 1479168000,
      "timeout": 1510704000,
      "since": 481824
    }
  }
}
```

The `blocks` field is the current number of blocks in the block chain. You can also get this information from [BlockExplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/) or use the [Direct Link](http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount) to the block count.

If you want the size in bytes, look at the size of your `blk0001.dat` file, currently 528Mb.

Comment: Upvoted. Interesting file size though, mine is only 550MB.

Comment: Thanks for that correction. I was checking on a machine that had multiple copies of many blocks in it. (Don't ask.)

Comment: @David Schartz How did you know that there were multiple copies in the block database files?

Comment: It was due to a bug I introduced while working on the bitcoin client. I didn't realize they were still there. I figured when I fixed the bug, they'd go away. It's strange, the client still works perfectly fine with them there. (I'm cleaning them out now.)

Answer (score 4):

Go to http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount.

Other statistics are available at http://blockexplorer.com/q.

Comment: Is the block size in bytes always the same or is there something like an average block size?

Comment: It depends on how many transactions are in the block. You can find out the size of a block by looking at it on http://blockexplorer.com/. The average size for the last 1000 blocks (which will be not representative of the entire chain) is roughly 22Kb (http://blockexplorer.com/q/avgblocksize).