# Where on the web can I find out the current total blockchain size?

Tags: blockchain

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/262/516) partially asked the same thing, but only got a response for viewing the size when you have the client installed.

I want to know the total blockchain size without having to install the client and download the blockchain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blockchain.info has many useful stats.

http://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size

Comment: They should add annotations to that graph, like Google Trends. The first annotation in May would of course be satoshiDice.

Comment: So 1847MB is the current total size? For some reason I thought it was over 2GB.

Comment: That reports the size of the data stored, not including headers and indexes.

Right now, blk0001.dat is at its max, 2.1 GB, blk0002.dat is 0.5 GB, and blkindex.dat is at 0.9 GB.   So a total of about 3.5 GB.